# Submitting form data issue

Tags: php, javascript, html

Ok super simple and I'm sure it'll be solved in 10 mins flat.

I have a form, nice, the form submits data to a PHP file on my server (which then sends it to a MYSQL database and redirects the page)

The submit button is actually a normal button that I have given a submit code. 
This is top stop the "Enter submitting the form" problem, I don't need to disable Enter, just stop it from submitting.

First time I use the button it works fine, data is sent, redirect happens great.

If I come back to the page, and submit again, nothing goes to the PHP script and I get the generic data submit page.

```
<input type="button" style="position:absolute; left:639px; top:1669px; width:81px; height:22px; /*Tag Style*/"       id="butn_7" value="Submit" onclick="submit()" __AddCode="here">
```

That's the button I'm using, if I use a normal Submit button it works fine over and over but I have that annoying problem of Enter submitting the form.

This is the form header

```
<form id="form_28" name="egumemsurvey" onsubmit="return validate_form_28(this)" action="http://mrrsystems.net/blerg.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" target="_self" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin:0px; /*MainDivStyle*/" __AddCode="here">
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Cheers

Paddy

Comment: IGNORE THIS, I AM A SIMPLETON

Comment: Did you have a link to the wrong page and were going to an older version of it or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display the results, when you return to the page, it is necessary to send them to the page.
If you want validate your form, then you need stop form submit; check the form using js-validation or send your data to the server, and when come results of checking you can submit the form, or show errors to the user.